# How can i detect the forehead region using opencv and dlib?

Tags: python, opencv, dlib, facial-identification

I want to detect the forehead region for research purposes.

I have tried taking the width of my roi as the distance between the leftmost point of the left eye and the rightmost point of the right eye. This seems to work as far as width is concerned however when it comes to height i need a solution that works for all people. Note i do not want hair to appear in my roi. I have an implementation of the height but it does not work for all people.

```py
x = int((shape[21][0]+shape[22][0])/2)
y = int((shape[21][1]+shape[22][1])/2)
w = abs(shape[39][0]-shape[42][0])
h = abs(y-shape[29][1])

y_mid = int((y + (y - h)) / 2)
roi = image[y-h:y_mid,int(x-w/2):int(x+w/2)]

if(roi.shape[0] !=0 and roi.shape[1] != 0):
    roi = imutils.resize(roi, width=250, inter=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    cv2.imshow('ROI', roi)

cv2.rectangle(image,(int(x-w/2), int(y-h)), (int(x + w/2), y_mid), (0, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imshow('Image', image)
```

Comment: please show examples of when it doesn't work as intended

Comment: And how do you plan to work out the forehead of people without hair?

Comment: detect the face and eyes using dlib. Now take the eyes detect points as lower reference and redraw by removing the lower portion of the eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Code for detecting forehead :

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageDraw
import os
#image=cv2.imread(img_path)
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("16.png")
face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(unknown_image) # detects all the faces in image
t = len(face_locations)
print(len(face_locations))
print(face_locations)
face_landmarks_list = face_recognition.face_landmarks(unknown_image)
# Drawing rectangles over the faces
pil_image = PIL.Image.fromarray(unknown_image)
for face_location in face_locations:
    #print(face_location)
    top,right,bottom,left =face_location
    draw_shape = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(pil_image)
    im = PIL.Image.open("16.png")
    #bottom=34
    k = face_landmarks_list[0]['right_eyebrow']
    bottom= face_landmarks_list[0]['right_eyebrow'][0][1]
    for k1 in k :   
        if(bottom>k1[1]):
            bottom=k1[1]
    k = face_landmarks_list[0]['left_eyebrow']
    lbottom= face_landmarks_list[0]['left_eyebrow'][0][1]
    for k1 in k :   
        if(lbottom>k1[1]):
            lbottom=k1[1]
    bottom=min(bottom,lbottom)
    print(bottom)
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    im.save("m2.jpg")    
    draw_shape.rectangle([left, top, right, bottom],outline="blue")
```