# Is there a way to get the area of the forehead (bounding box) by using opencv/dlib and for a live stream video

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, dlib

I've been working on a project to get the forehead area from a live streaming video and not just use and image and crop the forehead like from this example [How can i detect the forehead region using opencv and dlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57647638/how-can-i-detect-the-forehead-region-using-opencv-and-dlib).

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predict_path)


while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(gray) #detects number of faces present

    for face in faces:
        x1 = face.left()
        y1 = face.top()
        x2 = face.right()
        y2 = face.bottom()
        
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)
        
        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

        for n in range(68, 81):
            x = landmarks.part(n).x
            y = landmarks.part(n).y

            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

I managed to get the forehead region using the landmarks of using https://github.com/codeniko/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks/blob/master/shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks.dat

But what I need is the rectangle bounding box onto where the landmark is at detecting the forehead region. Is this possible to get? If not, what should I do to get the forehead region. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please take look at this https://github.com/aoxolotl/head-detector You can customize it to detect forehead

Comment: @Karthik Alright. Will take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already find the desired coordinates by:

```py
for face in faces:
    x1 = face.left()
    y1 = face.top()
    x2 = face.right()
    y2 = face.bottom()

    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

> But what I need is the rectangle bounding box onto where the landmark is at detecting the forehead region.

Then change the y-coordinates:

```py
cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1-100), (x2, y2-100), (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

***Update***

To stick to the forehead points, we need to get minimum and maximum `landmark` coordinates, then we need to draw rectangle.

Step1: Getting coordinates:

---

- 1. Initialize `x_pts` and `y_pts`
- 2. Store `landmark(n)` points into the arrays.

```py
for n in range(68, 81):
    x = landmarks.part(n).x
    y = landmarks.part(n).y

    x_pts.append(x)
    y_pts.append(y)

    cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)
```

Step 2: Drawing the rectangle around detected points

---

- 1. Get Minimum and Maximum points

```py
x1 = min(x_pts)
x2 = max(x_pts)
y1 = min(y_pts)
y2 = max(y_pts)

cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)
```

Result:

When I zoom to the webcam:

[image]

When I'm far away:

[image]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import dlib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_81_face_landmarks.dat")

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = detector(gray)  # detects number of faces present

    for face in faces:
        x1 = face.left()
        y1 = face.top()
        x2 = face.right()
        y2 = face.bottom()

        landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

        x_pts = []
        y_pts = []

        for n in range(68, 81):
            x = landmarks.part(n).x
            y = landmarks.part(n).y

            x_pts.append(x)
            y_pts.append(y)

            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 4, (0, 255, 0), -1)

        x1 = min(x_pts)
        x2 = max(x_pts)
        y1 = min(y_pts)
        y2 = max(y_pts)

        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)

    cv2.imshow("out", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I was stuck there and had no idea how to do it. But thanks for the answer! It did solve what I had asked for. However the box changes its position whenever we go closer/further from the camera. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It works if I was closer to the camera and the box does not stay on the forehead when we are far from the camera.. :(

Comment: Ok, then the constant parameter `-100` should be dynamic, let me work on that..

Comment: I will return back to you once I found the solution, I'm now working on it

Comment: Please replace previous with this one: `cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1 - int(x1 * 0.1), y1 - int(y1*0.5)), (x2 + int(x1 * 0.1), y2), (0, 0, 255), 3)`

Comment: Somehow when use the new line you gave, and I change the parameter values to get only the forehead, it still does not stick to the forehead. I'm also trying different values to get the forehead and only detects the forehead even when object is far

Comment: I have another idea, let me try that one

Comment: I think I solved or close to the solution this time. Please check out my update part of my answer.